# How to implement Remember me in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, remember-me

I have a login form and a remember me checkbox. I want the username and the password to be automatically filled in if the user checked the remember me checkbox on the previous login, but it is not working for now. I'm using the LoginController that was built in Laravel.

LoginController:

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::DASHBOARD;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Check either username or email.
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        $identity  = request()->get('identity');
        $fieldName = filter_var($identity, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'name';
        request()->merge([$fieldName => $identity]);
        return $fieldName;
    }

     /**
     * Validate the user login.
     * @param Request $request
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'identity' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ],
            [
                'identity.required' => 'Username or email is required',
                'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            ]
        );
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('login_error', trans('auth.failed'));
        throw ValidationException::withMessages(
            [
                'error' => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="topMargin container">
  <br><br>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" text-align="center">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

              <div class="card-body">
                  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                      @csrf

                      <div class="form-group row">
                          {{-- <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label> --}}

                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <input id="identity" type="identity" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('identity') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="identity" value="{{ old('identity') }}" placeholder="{{ __('Email or Username') }}" required autofocus>

                              @if ($errors->has('identity'))
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('identity') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @endif
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group row">
                          {{-- <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label> --}}

                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

                              @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @endif
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div style="text-align:center">
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                  </label>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div style="text-align:center">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                  {{ __('Login') }}
                              </button>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <div style="text-align:center">
                              <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                  {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                              </a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *"it is not working for now"*?

Comment: Update: I got the following code working.

if (auth()->attempt(['name' => $request->input('identity'), 'password' => $request->input('password')] , $remember_me)) {
            $user = auth()->user();
            dd($user);
}

I managed to display dd($user);
May I know how to fill in the fields?

Comment: It is better to use the edit link and put that information in the question itself. Make sure you only ask one question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the default Authentication provided by Laravel, meaning you do not need to do anything in your `Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController` to **remember** the user if you have the default form input name values in the `views/auth/login.blade.php` form, which it looks like you do!

The only thing you need to ensure is that in your `users` table you store a `remember_token` field.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#remembering-users

Answer (score 1):

```
public function webLoginPost(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);


    $remember_me = $request->has('remember_me') ? true : false; 


    if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')], $remember_me))
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        dd($user);
    }else{
        return back()->with('error','your username and password are wrong.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting code without an explination of what is going on is not particularly helpful. Where should OP add this code, how should they call it?

Comment: Remembering Users
If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout. Your users table must include the string remember_token column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token.

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: Hi, I managed to display dd($user); now. May I know how to fill in the fields?